# Output a string with a new character in each line, forming a right triangle

Tags: c, loops, char, c-strings, triangle

Trying to output a string that has been assigned to an array, with different characters on each new line, eventually creating a right triangle. But I'm completely stuck. I believe some for loops should be involved to iterate over each character but I don't know how to increase the array index on each new line to output one character more than the line before.

This is a sketch that allowed me to visualize this:

```
string[0]
string[1] + string[2]
string[3] + string[4] + string[5]
string[6] + string[7] + string[8] + string[9]
```

For example, let's take into account this line of code: `char string[50] = "Assignment";`

The output desired would look like this:

```
A
s s
i g n 
m e n t
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Think of the pattern you want to produce. It starts with **one** character, then go to the next line and print the next **two** characters; next line and print **three** characters...1, 2, 3. How can you produce the numbers 1, 2, 3, etc, and for each number print that many characters from the string? Start with that, and build on top of it

Comment: First create a program which prints just `*` to make the pyramid. Then create a *new* program, which prints the string one character per line. Then create a final program, which does what your assignment asks for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using only one while loop.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void triangle_output( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 1;
    size_t i = n;
    
    while ( *s )
    {
        if ( i-- == 0 )
        {
            putchar( '\n' );
            i = n++;
        }
        putchar( *s++ );
        putchar( ' ' );
    }
    
    if ( i != n - 1 ) putchar( '\n' );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "Assignment";
    
    triangle_output( s );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
A 
s s 
i g n 
m e n t
```

Or the function can be rewritten the following way

```
void triangle_output( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 1;
    size_t i = 0;
    
    while ( *s )
    {
        putchar( *s++ );
        putchar( ' ' );

        if ( ++i == n )
        {
            putchar( '\n' );
            i = 0;
            ++n;
        }
    }
    
    if ( i != 0 ) putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will print the triangle. If the string have enough chars to print the whole last line it will print `-`.

```
void printTriangle(const char *s)
{
    size_t length = strlen(s), pos = 0;
    for(size_t line = 1; line < -1; line++)
    {
        for(size_t ch = 1; ch <= line; ch++)
        {
            if(pos < length) printf("%c", *s++);
            else printf("-");
            pos++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        if(pos >= length) break;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    printTriangle("Assignment123");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xxM1eEY6a